# How to make a popup like div to appear outside the div containing it using react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

a dialog is shown on clicking a button. I want to display this dialog outside the div containing it.
this dialog div is within overlay div. this overlay div should be covering the entire screen and the dialog div is in the center of the screen.

below is my code, this shows the dialog div squeezed inside the div containing it.

```
function Parent() {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <GridView/> 
        </Wrapper>
    );
}

const Wrapper = styled(div)`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    flex: 1;
`;

function GridView() {
    return (
        <GridViewWrapper>
            <Cards>
                {items.map((item, index) => {

                    return (
                        <Card>
                           <Content to={toSomeUrl} />
                           <Footer>
                               <Name to={toSomeUrl}>
                                   <span>{item.name} </span> 
                                   <span>some</span>
                               </Name>
                               <ItemDialog/>
                           </Footer>
                       </Card>
                   );
               })}
           </Cards>
       </GridViewWrapper>
   );
```

}

```
const GridViewWrapper = styled.div`
    max-height: calc(100vh - 136px);
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
`;

const Cards = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-height: calc(${56px * 1.5});
    padding: 0 calc(50vw - 600px);
    @media screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
        padding: 0 calc(50vw - 400px);
    }
`;

 const Card = styled.div`
     max-width: 324px;
     height: 56px;
     width: calc(33.33% - 16px);
     @media screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
         width: calc(50% - 16px);
     }
     margin: 8px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: flex-end;
     background-image: url(${props => props.$bgUrl});
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: cover;
 `;


function ItemDialog() { //this contains the button and overlay with dialog
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <button onClick={onButtonClick}>click me</button>
            {isDialogOpen && 
                <Overlay onClick={() => {setDialogOpen(false)}}>
                    <Dialog>
                        <input type="text"/>
                        //somedivs
                    </Dialog>
                </Overlay>
            }
        </Wrapper>
    );
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px;
`;

const Overlay = styled.div`
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    bottom: 20px
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
`;

const Dialog = styled.div`
    width: 384px;
    max-height: calc(100% - 200px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
`;
```

I am not sure how to fix this problem. could someone help me with this? thanks.

Comment: Just make your dialog position fixed with a higher z-index then the overlay and smaller dimensions centred on the screen. Standard modal

Comment: thanks but i have tried position:fixed on dialog and its still the same. overlay is not occupying the width and height of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use fixed position in the modal to get it out to the global context?

Alternatively you could use react portal to anchor the react element to a tag outside the DOM tree.

https://es.reactjs.org/docs/portals.html